# Android Auto text sizing not working

Tags: android, textview, android-appcompat, autosize

I am trying to make my application responsive by putting the auto resize text option but it seems that its not working. I am using the android auto size tag :

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="60px"
        android:paddingTop="160px"
        android:text="@string/greetings1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="5sp"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```

When I run it on my phone it does not resize at all.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**`Autosizing TextViews`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

> If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the
>   value "wrap_content" for the layout_width or layout_height attributes
>   of a TextView. It may produce unexpected results.

You should bound Height

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Comment: but fixing the height would not cause issue for different android screens ? as I read somewhere that we should not hard code the widths and heights attribs ?

Comment: your idea of changing height worked but still not sure if I hard code the height then will it cause issue on different devices or not.